# Call a method from inside another class in Python

Tags: python, functional-testing, fixtures, nose

I have some Python tests that I run with Nose.
An example is this:

```
class Logout(unittest.TestCase):

    def report_pass_fail(self):
        #code

    def setUp(self):
        #code

    def test_Logout(self):
        #code

    def tearDown(self):
        #code
```

Because I have a very big amount of tests and because i want to create a modular code architecture....i would like to have the report_pass_fail , setUp and tearDown methods inside a separate file(module) and just call them when needed inside the test's class.

I am not very experienced in OOP .I tried several combinations but with no success.
How could I do that?

The module I created is this:

```
import json, httplib, base64, unittest, sys
from selenium import webdriver
import className
from creds import config, sauce_hub

class Fixtures(unittest.TestCase):
    def report_pass_fail(self):
        base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (config['username'], config['access-key']))[:-1]
        result = json.dumps({'public': 'true', 'passed': sys.exc_info() == (None, None, None)})
        connection = httplib.HTTPConnection("saucelabs.com")
        connection.request('PUT', '/rest/v1/%s/jobs/%s' % (config['username'], self.wd.session_id), result, headers={"Authorization": "Basic %s" % base64string})
        result = connection.getresponse()
        return result.status == 200

    def setUp(self):
        desired_capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
        desired_capabilities['version'] = '4'
        desired_capabilities['platform'] = 'Linux'
        desired_capabilities['name'] = className.getName(self)
        desired_capabilities['record-video'] = False

        self.wd = webdriver.Remote(desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities,
                                   command_executor="http://" + config['username'] + ":" + config['access-key'] + sauce_hub)
        self.wd.implicitly_wait(10)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.wd.quit()
```

And its use in the test file is something like this:

```
import unittest
from fixture_module import Fixtures
#is_alert_present(wd)

#credentials



class DeleteLectureFromCoursePanel(Fixtures,unittest.TestCase):

    import fixture_module

    f = fixture_module.Fixtures()
    f.report_pass_fail()

    f.setUp()

    def test_DeleteLectureFromCoursePanel(self):
        success = True
        wd = self.wd
        wd.find_element_by_link_text("Delete").click()
        self.assertEqual("Are you sure?", wd.switch_to_alert().text)
        wd.switch_to_alert().accept()
        self.assertTrue(success)

    f.tearDown()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

It seems ok and there are no errors in PyCharmIDE but when I run it from console it says :

```
ValueError:no such test method in <class 'fixture_module.Fixtures'> : runTest
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making this much much more complicated than it needs to be. If your `DeleteLectureFromCoursePanel` inherits from `Fixtures`, it *already* gets the methods defined in that class. They will be called automatically by the test runner, and there's no reason for you to call them manually (especially within the class body like that).

There's also no need for you to additionally inherit from `TestCase`. You get that already via `Fixtures`.

Comment: Hello Daniel and thank you for the response! I removed the inheritance from TestCase from the DeleteLectureFromCoursePanel and I deleted the import and the instantiation inside the test class. Now it works as i wanted.The methods are called automatically.I think I now have a better grasp of OOP in Python. Thanks again!